# How to change positions of UITabBarItems according to certain situations in the app, programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

I have 3 items in my UITabBar and my app runs 2 Languages(English and Arabic). I need to change the position of the items when the app is switched to Arabic since A Right to Left reading is required[image: TabBar Items]

ie. the Tab called "One Way" must appear at the right side and Multi City has to appear at the left side. Is there a way to do that?

I tried this method but That was not allowed

```
 UITabBarItem *realItemOne=[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *realItemTwo=[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *realItemThree=[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    if (_isEnglish) {
        self.tabBar.items=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:realItemOne,realItemTwo,realItemThree, nil];
    }
    else{
        self.tabBar.items=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:realItemThree,realItemTwo,realItemOne, nil];
    }
```

Also Tried this

```
self.tabBar.items=[[self.tabBar.items reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];
```

Another method that I tried

```
UIViewController *viewControllerOne=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    UIViewController *viewControllerTwo=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    UIViewController *viewControllerThree=[self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2];
    if (_isEnglish) {
        NSArray *englishOrder=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:viewControllerOne,viewControllerTwo,viewControllerThree, nil];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:englishOrder];
    }
    else{
        NSArray *arabicOrder=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:viewControllerThree,viewControllerTwo,viewControllerOne, nil];
        [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:arabicOrder];
    }
```

Comment: Check my answer @Sidharth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
[image]
[image]This worked for me:

Place this code in the TabBArController ViewWillAppear method

```
 NSArray *actualItems= self.viewControllers;

    NSArray* reversedArray = [[actualItems reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects];


    [self setViewControllers:reversedArray animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not change items, change just text and image of tab item.

```
if (_isEnglish) { change just image and text on 0. and 2. tab } else { also just change image and text }
```

when the user tap on the item, you check for language and then do appropriate method. If user tap on 0. element and the language is english, you call oneWay method and if language is arabic you call multiCity

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the number of controllers in tabBarController in NSArray format as below:

```
NSArray *vcArray = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
```

Now change the sequence of the objects of this "vcArray" as you want(for demo purpose I have used 3 controllers. you can put your logic whatever you want) and then re-assign "vcArray" to your tabBarController like below:

```
self.tabbarController.viewControllers = vcArray;
```

---

Actual code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
    SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
    ThirdViewController *tvc = [[ThirdViewController alloc] init];

    fvc.tabBarItem.title = @"First";
    svc.tabBarItem.title = @"Second";
    tvc.tabBarItem.title = @"Third";

    _tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    _tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:fvc, svc, tvc, nil];

    self.window.rootViewController = _tbc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

--------------- A method to swap controllers in tabViewController in AppDelegate -----------

```
NSArray *arr = self.tbc.viewControllers; //here self means appDelegate

self.tbc.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:arr[2], arr[1], arr[0], nil];
```

Hope this helps!

Attached images for your reference.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have tried an extended version of this. I have posted the code along with the question

Comment: Check my answer @SidharthJDev